# Display MathJax equations smoothly and only once they are fully rendered

Tags: css, web, mathjax

I'm using MathJax equations on my website and would like to figure out a way to configure MathJax in such a way that the equations initially do not appear at all (while the site is still loading) and only fade in smoothly once they are fully rendered?

Is this possible, and how should I go about trying to implement this?

I have experimented with

```
EqnChunk: 100,
EqnChunkFactor: 1,
EqnChunkDelay: 10,
```

but am not seeing much of an effect. There is still the "preliminary rendering" (where, I believe, MathJax is figuring out the height and width of the surrounding glyphs) that occurs before the final rendering.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Is server-side rendering an option for you?

Comment: My site is hosted on Github, so server-side rendering is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Not that that's a real problem but ok. You might want to explain what you are after with "fade in smoothly". Obviously, you can't know the dimensions of the results without having generated them so some jitter is inevitable; unless you hide the page entirely until MathJax is done.

Comment: I was under the impression that server-side rendering was not possible on Github Pages. I'd be happy to be corrected. I was hoping it would be possible to write a script that would wait until all MathJax is rendered and only then display all of the math. In place of the math I was hoping to get whitespace while rendering. And if the appearance of the equations were "smooth" in the sense that they take about a second to "fade in" once fully rendered that would be ideal.

Comment: You're right that GitHub does not offer anything, but you could use travis for such processing. As Davide Cervone commeted, without a live example, it's hard to give any advice beyond disabling the fast preview and setting the chunking high (or do something like http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-all-at-once.html)

Comment: I have a similar problem I am saving the equation in ckeditor from mathjax equation editor and when i am loading the editor or previewing the editor I am seeing for a sec the tex code and then the equation fully rendered. is there a way to avoid this flicker.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably are seeing is the "fast preview" that is created during the input phase before the final output is generated.  You can prevent that using

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "fast-preview": {disabled: true},
  tex2jax: {preview: "none"}
});
</script>
```

(Assuming you are using TeX input.  If you are using MathML or AsciiMath, you will need to change the `tex2jax` to `mml2jax` or `asciimath2jax`.)

Comment: Unfortunately this setting, which I have tried before, completely deactivates rendering of mathematics and the TeX markup appears on the website in its place.

Comment: Then you have done something wrong.  If you can produce a page that exhibits the problem, we can see what went wrong.